# Azure AD B2C client workflow vs server workflow

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm looking into using Azure AD B2C for our Xamarin.Forms mobile app. I've used it previously for a web app and want to use it for our mobile app. I have an Azure AD B2C and Azure Mobile backend created already and am setting up the login page.

What I can't find are the differences between the client workflow and server workflow. Are there any guidelines as to when and why you would choose one over the other? I've googled this but can't seem to find any useful documents or links anywhere.

Comment: Documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-apps

Comment: This could be helpful: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Azure-Active-Directory-B2C-Authentication-For-Mobile-with-Matthew-Soucoup

Comment: That video looks useful, let me check that out :)